# Entity Framework Core and many to many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to migrate a small application to Entity Framework Core but I cant get the many to many relation to work.
First my `Entities`

```
public class Currency : Entity<int>, IMayHaveUser
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CountryCurrency> CountryCurrencies { get; set; }
    public bool IsUserDefined => User != null;
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
}
public class Country : Entity<int>, IMayHaveUser 
{
    public string Iso2Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Era> Eras { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CountryCurrency> CountryCurrencies { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsUserDefined => User != null;
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
}
public class CountryCurrency : Entity<Guid>
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}
```

and my DbContext is

> modelBuilder.Entity().HasKey(currency => new {
>   currency.CountryId, currency.CurrencyId });
>       modelBuilder.Entity()
>               .HasOne(pt => pt.Country)
>               .WithMany(p => p.CountryCurrencies)
>               .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CountryId);
>
> ```
>     modelBuilder.Entity<CountryCurrency>()
>         .HasOne(pt => pt.Currency)
>         .WithMany(t => t.CountryCurrencies)
>         .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CurrencyId);
> ```

now when I add a currency for example

> ```
>   Currency currency;
>         Country country;
>         CountryCurrency countryCurrency;
>
>         currency = new Currency();
>         currency.Id = i++;
>         currency.User = null;
>         currency.Code = "ETB";
>         currency.Name = "Ethiopian Birr";
>         currency.Symbol = "Br";
>
>         country =
>             this._context.Countries.FirstOrDefault(
>                 country1 => country1.Iso2Code == "ET");
>
>         if (country != null)
>         {
>             currency.CountryCurrencies = new List<CountryCurrency>();
>             countryCurrency = new CountryCurrency();
>             countryCurrency.Country = country;
>             countryCurrency.Currency = currency;
>             currency.CountryCurrencies.Add(countryCurrency);
>             this.InitialCurrencies.Add(currency);
>         }
>         this._context.Currencies.Add(currency);
> ```

so when now I'm retrieve the data in my test I get this with this code

```
Country = context.Countries.Include(country => country.CountryCurrencies).First();
```

[image: Debugger]

I can't get the currency the id is set but the property not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have also to include the currency entity, not just the join entity

```
Country = context.Countries
    .Include(country => country.CountryCurrencies)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.Currency)
    .First();
```